# How to set the creation date of a file in C under Mac OS X?

Tags: c, macos

Mac OS X stores file creation time, and I know how to read it with `stat()` from `<sys/stat.h>`.

I could not find a way, how to set the creation time in C. It must be possible somehow, as the utility `SetFile` can do it (`SetFile` is part of the command line tools package from Apple):

```
SetFile -d '12/31/1999 23:59:59' file.txt
```

How can I do it in C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [utimes](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=utimes&sektion=2).

> If    times is non-NULL, it is assumed to point to an array of two timeval
>        structures.  The access time is set to the value of the first element,
>        and the modification time is set to the value of the second element.

And:

> For
>        file systems that support file birth (creation) times (such as UFS2), the
>        birth time will be set to the value of the second element if the second
>        element is older than the currently set birth time.  To set both a birth
>        time and a modification time, two calls are required; the first to set
>        the birth time and the second to set the (presumably newer) modification
>        time

As an example:

```
struct timeval times[2];
memset(times, 0, sizeof(times));

times[0].seconds = 946684799;  /* 31 Dec 1999 23:59:59 */
times[1].seconds = 946684799;

utimes("/path/to/file", &times);
```

If the modification time passed is older than the current creation time of the file, the creation time will be set.  You can then call `utimes` again if you want to set a different modification time.

Comment: Ah, I was missing the second piece of information. If I understand correctly, I can only set the birth time to an older date than the current birth time? Can't I set it to a newer date?

Comment: The manpage for `utimes` that ships with current versions of OS X (I checked 10.10), is from 1993 and it does not mention the birth time support. However, this does indeed work on OS X 10.10.5 with a minor change: Instead of `seconds` use `tv_sec` on the `times` array.

Answer (score 3):

By looking how osxfuse loopback filesystem implements setting creation time here:
https://github.com/osxfuse/filesystems/blob/master/filesystems-c/loopback/loopback.c

It seems that you need to use setattrlist():
https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/setattrlist.2.html

Seems (from the loopback.c) the code would be along the lines of:

```
struct attrlist attributes;

attributes.bitmapcount = ATTR_BIT_MAP_COUNT;
attributes.reserved = 0;
attributes.commonattr = ATTR_CMN_CRTIME;
attributes.dirattr = 0;
attributes.fileattr = 0;
attributes.forkattr = 0;
attributes.volattr = 0;

res = setattrlist(path, &attributes, &crtime,
                  sizeof(struct timespec), FSOPT_NOFOLLOW);
```

Where "crtime" is struct timespec. See the man link above for the necessary includes.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the stat(2) man-page, it refers to utimes(2) in the SEE ALSO section.

```
NAME
 futimes, utimes -- set file access and modification times

LIBRARY
 Standard C Library (libc, -lc)

SYNOPSIS
 #include <sys/time.h>

 int
 futimes(int fildes, const struct timeval times[2]);

 int
 utimes(const char *path, const struct timeval times[2]);
```